# Get Facebook user work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write some application that scan user's group posts. When I read the group feed posts using the API  I’m interested to get some information on the one who posted this post ('from' field). The graph API today gives only the id and the name of this person. I'm interested also in his work place. I tried taking the user id and to access the / resource and to get his work field , but this field is not returned. When I’m looking on the same user profile in Facebook I see his work place is public, even I’m not connected with him.
Anything I can do to get this user work with the existing Facebook API?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if the work history info is not public, you'll need the **"user_work_history"** permission (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-extended-profile).

If it's public, you can try calling the

```
/{USER_ID}?fields=id,work
```

Comment: Thanks, but if this user is not a user of my application is there any way i can get his work?

Comment: As I wrote, if it's public, you should be able to issue the above call

Comment: user_work_history has been was deprecated on April 4, 2018.